# node.js server doesn't load properly

Tags: node.js, server

I used the code below in my terminal and the page doesn't show and load properly. Why?

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('url', req.url);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.end('<h1>Hellooooooooooooooo</h1>');
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: do you have typo in the response.end ? it should be response.send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('url', req.url);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end('<h1>Hellooooooooooooooo</h1>');
});
server.listen(3000);
```

**you need to replace response with res, response is not defined**